# Canvas rendering not working when zoomlevel (devicePixelRatio) is larger than 1

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a button creator, which transforms a dom node into an image file. It works fine when the user has not changed the zoomlevel of the browser (or sometimes the browser has a larger default zoomlevel on large resolutions, e.g. FF on a MS Surface).

Basically on any occasion when window.devicePixelRatio is larger than 1 the rendering is bad.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>  
<script>
function dom2image(el)
{
    var canvas= document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var h = el.offsetHeight;
    var w = el.offsetWidth;

    canvas.width =  w;
    canvas.height = h;
    var html = el.outerHTML;
    var tempImg = document.createElement('img');
    tempImg.addEventListener('load', onTempImageLoad)
    tempImg.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="'+w+'" height="'+h+'"><foreignObject  width="100%" height="100%"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'+html+'</div></foreignObject></svg>')

    function onTempImageLoad(e)
    {
        ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0);
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.style.setProperty('width',w+'px');
        img.style.setProperty('height',h+'px');
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL();   
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(img);  
    }

    var dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
    console.log(dpr);
}

</script>
</head>
<body style='padding-bottom:10px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;'>
<div id='myelem' style='font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;padding:5px;border:1px blue solid;text-align:center;width:100px;border-radius:5px;'>Click here</div>
<br />
</body>
</html>
<script>dom2image(document.getElementById('myelem'));</script>
```

I noticed that the width (var w) and the height (var h) seems to differ depending on the value of window.devicePixelRatio. Borders disappear and the font quality is fuzzy also.

How can I make sure that the image is created successfully on any resolution or zoom level?

help appreciated

PS I am using the latest version of Firefox for testing.

PS2: edited the code a bit as it did not work in Chrome

Comment: Hi there, why did you reverted the changes? I wanted to help making your code executable (so easily testeable)

Comment: In any case you could try to multiply the width and height by the devicePixelRatio to adjust the size of the "physical pixels" to the size of the "CSS pixels" when creating the canvas

Comment: sorry about the changes, but thought it would be more clear this way :). I tried rescaling it also but the new pixel width/height don't seem to correspond with the pixelratio exactly. Also any change seem to blur the whole image